# When is this site going public?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long will the site stay in private beta?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-long-will-the-site-stay-in-private-beta)

Just a quick question - are we going into public beta tomorrow? Or is that later? Would appreciate it if you can give us some idea so we know how long we have to get things in shape.