# Why is IslamSE still in it's 'beta' version? btw What is beta here?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

There is this question "[How long will the site stay in private beta?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/11938)"

It talks about private beta & public beta.

Here are my questions?

1.) Which beta is IslamSE now (public or private and what are they)? 
2.) Why is still this a beta version, when other SE sites with traffic lower than this have got a logo.
3.) When can an SE site get a logo of their own?
4.) What to do to get out of this beta game. I mean how much traffic/day expected or what other features expected to go to higher level?

This might too broad, I'm sorry. But you can make the answer short if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been in public beta since June 26, 2012.

The site metrics (traffic etc) are useful for taking the pulse of the site, but they're but one of many factors that goes into deciding whether a site deserves to graduate.  In short, the site will stay in beta for as long as it needs to to build a stable community.

The overall health of the community is a very subjective thing to measure (metrics really can only take you so far), but can mostly be read by voting and site/meta activity.  Are good questions/answers getting upvoted and bad questions/answers getting downvoted?  Are problematic posts getting closed and/or deleted quickly, or are they lingering until moderator intervention is needed?  Are problems and concerns getting brought up in meta and prompting healthy discussion?

In other words, is the community working to [build a site it can be proud of](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1157/22)?  And above all else, is it succeeding in its ultimate purpose, namely giving actual focussed answers to questions with a minimum of noise?

Comment: what about the logo? How to get one?

Comment: @Wiser One of the first things that'll be done on graduation is SE's graphic design team will give the whole site a professional facelift; that includes the logo.

Comment: No reason you can't open a meta discussion to discuss what you want the site (and logo) to look like when it *does* graduate (they'll still design it as they see fit, and it still won't have any effect until the site actually *graduates*, but they do take community opinion into consideration)